# How do I disable the taxonomy term page?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I would like to disable the taxonomy/term/1 page that list the nodes using that taxonomy term. I have found some modules for older Drupal versions, but I haven't found quite what I'm looking for in Drupal 8.

Is there a configuration setting I am missing? Can I use a hook to disable the taxonomy term page, or does this require a module?

Comment: only for one term or for all the vocabulary?

Comment: All terms in a vocabulary - and all terms period. We don't want to enable exploring the site via Taxonomy Term pages.

Comment: in this case check my answer and you will find your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module can help you in this task

> Rabbit Hole is a module that adds the ability to control what should
>   happen when an entity is being viewed at its own page.

You need to enable the Rabbit Hole and Rabbit Hole taxonomy submodule and then in the admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/YOUR_VOCABULARY page you will see the Rabbit Hole Options.

Comment: it doesn't help in this issue! I just want to prevent drupal from listing nodes in taxonomy page.

Comment: @shekoufeh your problem is different from the problem asked in the question.

Answer (score 23):

A lightweight solution is to simply edit the taxonomy term view :
/admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term

... and restrict the access.

Comment: it is the best solution. you saved me a lot of time and energy. thanks.

Comment: Simple and easy without needing to install anything. This should be the selected answer!!!

Comment: Why not disabling this view all together?

Comment: When you use this solution, and you make use of the taxonomy menu module (drupal/taxonomy_menu), there will be no menu items in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a *Content revision: ID* filter. Set the operator to *Is equal to*, and input `-1`
2. Click *Add* in the *No results behavior* options box and add *Response status code*
3. Select *404 (Not Found)* as the status code to return and add it
4. Save the view

Step 1 adds a filter that will always fail, because revision ids are positive integers, thus never equal `-1`. This will make the query always return with no results.

Steps 2 and 3 make Drupal return a proper 404 HTTP code when no results are returned from the query.